# Multiple Conditions in Validation Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am more or less a regex novice. I tried to get the following conditions into a regex:

- No White Space at the beginning and at the end of a string
- Allow all digits
- Allow spaces, points, brackets, plus and minus

Resulted in the following regex:

```
^\S[\d\/. ()\-+]*\S$
```

But now i try to apply two more conditions:

- Allow only one or two +
- Allow only one ( and one )

My problem is how to merge those two conditions into the existing regex string above cuz excluding + `[+]{1,2}` and () `[(]{1} [)]{1}` doesn't make much sense cuz i try to make general statements in no particular order so that i would be able to chain it. Thanks Ralf

Comment: And you want to prevent `)301( 269-3451` (so the open parenthesis must precede the close parenthesis), and you want to disallow `(301 269-3451` (open without close, or conversely close without open, though that might be caught as close before open). Can the string start with a minus or point? Could `(+- . -+)` be valid?  Why didn't you say it wasn't? Your `^\S` allows any letter at the beginning; that probably isn't what you want.  Also, which sub-species of regex are you planning to use?  The answer for PCRE is different from `awk` or `sed` or ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
^(?=\S)(?=(?:[^+]*\+){0,2}[^+]*$)(?=(?:[^(]*\()?[^(]*$)(?=(?:[^)]*\))?[^)]*$)[- .()+0-9]*[-.+()0-9]$
```

In **[the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aP0qH2/4)** you can play with the input to check what matches and doesn't.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The lookahead `(?=\S)` asserts that what follows is a non-space character
- Lookahead `(?=(?:[^+]*\+){0,2}[^+]*$)` : two `+` chars at the most
- Lookahead `(?=(?:[^(]*\()?[^(]*$)` : One `(` at the most
- Lookahead `(?=(?:[^)]*\))?[^)]*$)` : One `)` at the most
- `[- .()+0-9]*` zero or more of the allowed chars
- `[-.+()0-9]` end with one of the allowed chars that is not a space
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works exactly as planned. But i think i have to work through your explanations to actually understand everything. A few new bits i haven't seen yet. ;)

Comment: I recommend you start with the second article in the reference section as the explanation is at a much more comfortable pace. The technique is the same—this is similar to a password-validation regex.

Comment: Yep the first link i already knew, ran across it a few hours ago while researching. But it's a bit too high paced. The other link seems much more suitable for my current level. Perfect. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of those `\S`, they are wrong. Each one will match *any* non-whitespace character, so if for instance I put a `$` at the beginning of the phone numer, it will still match.

```
^[\d\/. ()\-+]+$
```

Now, let's add some conditions, and for that, we can use lookaheads:

- One or two `+`: `(?=[^+]*(?:\+[^+]+){0,2}[^+]*$)` (non-consecutive and not at the end of a string)
- One `(` and one `)`: `(?=[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\))?[^()]*$)`

So the expression becomes:

```
^(?=[^+]*(?:\+[^+]+){0,2}[^+]*$)(?=[^()]*(?:\([^()]*\))?[^()]*$)[\d\/. ()\-+]+$
```

Regex101: http://regex101.com/r/xW5pS7/1

This technique lets you basically apply multiple regexes over the same matched string to add constraints. The lookaheads have a `$` anchor at the end, so they both have to match the whole string.

But I have a feeling your requiremens are too loose, and this expression will match *too much*. If you can think of more precise rules, I'll include them in my answer.