# How to make multiple RegEx conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have `<input type='text' placeholder='Email or nickname' />`. Can I validate `email` and `nickname` by one pattern?

`const emailRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/`

`const usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/`

Can I combine these two patterns into one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Conditions in Validation Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922540/multiple-conditions-in-validation-regex)

Comment: I can't understand how to merge these patterns

Comment: Why not just use or?
`const valid = emailRegex.test(val) || usernameRegex.test(val)` - added benefit: Easier to read and understand

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` is really short for TLD. Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)